# Write a list with multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a list with multiple dataframes (more than 200 dataframes), for that purpose i use the following syntax:

`> list.name <- list(ls(pattern="dfname*"))`

this let me create a `list.name` with multiple object and when i try to print the content of the list there is no problem

```
> list.name
[[1]]
[1] "dfname1" "dfname2" "dfname3" "dfname4" "dfname5"
.....
[200] "dfname200" "dfname201" "dfname202" ....
```

but, when i try to see a specific dataframe in my list `list.name` i can't see the dataframe value, for example

```
> list.name[[5]]
Error en list.name[[5]] : subíndice fuera de  los límites (subscript out of range)
```

or

```
> list.name[2]
[[1]]
NULL
```

I need to built a list that let me do other operations like view `str` of each dataframe and export each dataframe to csv, etc.

Could you please give me some suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `as.list` instead of `list` in the first code line

Comment: You don't understand list indexing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the

Comment: @GavinSimpson - pressed enter to soon looking for link

Comment: Thanks gagolew, i already create the list, but still i can't see the dataframe values. For example, i try to see de object allocated in 'list.name[[2]]' and the only thing that i can see is the dataframe name '> list.name[[2]]' [1] "dfname2"'. Thanks

Comment: MrFlick's answer is what you're looking for, take a look at it and try to use it with your data/names, it works like a charm. Also see @Gavin Simpson good explanation.

Comment: +1 I don't see what is wrong here; the OP tried something and is mistaken in how this all works. Being mistaken in how something works doesn't warrant a -1 FFS. What is wrong with people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls()` will just return a character vector with the names of the matching data.frames. If you actually want to create a list of the data.frames you should use

```
dflist <- mget(ls(pattern="dfname*"))
```

or if you do just want the names, my not keep it in vector form rather than converting to list

```
list.name <- list(ls(pattern="dfname*"))
```

then you can extract each name with

```
list.name[1]
```

rather than using the double-bracket syntax. There's really no need for a list in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You have simply created a list of length 1, that contains a vector of 200 names.  You haven't stored the dataframes themselves.  To actually create a list of all the data frames, you can try

```
lists <- lapply(ls(pattern="dfname*"), get)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a list out of the character vector of object names. You want to `get()` the object behind each name and make a list from those. In this case, you want the `mget()` function to get lots of objects at once from their names. This returns a list

```
## dummy data
dfname1 <- dfname2 <- dfname3 <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = LETTERS[1:3])

dfnames <- ls(pattern="dfname*")
list.name <- mget(dfnames)
str(list.name)

> str(list.name)
List of 3
 $ dfname1:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ A: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ B: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ dfname2:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ A: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ B: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ dfname3:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ A: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ B: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3

list.name[[ dfnames[1] ]]

> list.name[[ dfnames[1] ]]
  A B
1 1 A
2 2 B
3 3 C
```